# Maven could not resolve dependencies when using mvn test version number

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, dependencies, version

Hello I have two spring boot modules, a mediator class and a mockserver class. The mediator class has the parent pom and the mockserver class has the child pom. They both have two spring boot apps on their respective ports.

I am trying to add a dependency to the mockserver class pom for the mediator class like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nulogix</groupId>
    <artifactId>billing_mediator</artifactId>
    <version>${nulogix-release-number}-${git.version.number}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
```

When I run mvn test though I get this error and I do not know why because the version is being copied from the parent POM.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project mock_server: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.nulogix:mock_server:jar:0.9.6_M2-${git.commit.time}.${git.commit.id.describe-short}: Failure to find com.nulogix:billing_mediator:jar:0.9.6-M2
```

Here is my mediator pom file:

```
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.nulogix</groupId>
    <artifactId>billing_mediator</artifactId>
    <version>${nulogix-release-number}-${git.version.number}</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>billing</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>0.14.0</maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>
        <jaxb2-specVersion>2.2</jaxb2-specVersion>
        <git-commit-id-plugin.version>2.2.4</git-commit-id-plugin.version>
        <nulogix-release-number>0.9.6_M2</nulogix-release-number>
        <git.version.number>${git.commit.time}.${git.commit.id.describe-short}</git.version.number>
        <nulogix-billing-response-schema>nulogixBillingResponse_1.1.xsd</nulogix-billing-response-schema>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformats-text</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0.pr1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-jaxb2-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>id1-generate-service-end-point-from-wsdl</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <specVersion>${jaxb2-specVersion}</specVersion>
                            <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>*.wsdl</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/xjc/billing_endpoint</generateDirectory>
                            <generatePackage>com.nulogix.billing.service</generatePackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>id2-generate-pojo-from-request-xsd</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <specVersion>${jaxb2-specVersion}</specVersion>
                            <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/request</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>StudyDetailsSchema_3.17.6.12.xsd</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/request</bindingDirectory>
                            <bindingIncludes>
                                <include>StudyDetailsSchema_3.17.6.12.xjb</include>
                            </bindingIncludes>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/xjc/request_model</generateDirectory>
                            <generatePackage>com.nulogix.billing.model.request</generatePackage>                            
                        </configuration>                
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>id3-generate-pojo-from-response-xsd</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <specVersion>${jaxb2-specVersion}</specVersion>
                            <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/response</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>${nulogix-billing-response-schema}</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/xjc/response_model</generateDirectory>                           
                            <generatePackage>com.nulogix.billing.model.response</generatePackage>                   
                        </configuration>                
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
                  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> <!-- surefire plugin version managed by Spring Boot -->
   <configuration>
      <skipTests>true</skipTests>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>unit-tests</id>
      <phase>test</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>test</goal>
       </goals>
       <configuration>
         <skipTests>false</skipTests>
         <includes>
           <include>**/*Test.java</include>
         </includes>
       </configuration>
     </execution>
     <execution>
       <id>integration-tests</id>
       <phase>integration-test</phase>
       <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
       </goals>
       <configuration>
         <skipTests>false</skipTests>
         <includes>
           <include>**/*IT.*</include>
        </includes>
       </configuration>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <dateFormat>yyyyMMdd-HHmmss</dateFormat><!--  human-readable part of the version id -->
                    <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile><!-- somehow necessary. otherwise the variables are not available in the pom -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                  <configuration>
                    <archive>
                      <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Version>${nulogix-release-number}-${git.version.number}</Implementation-Version>
                        <Git-Version-Number>${git.version.number}</Git-Version-Number>
                      </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                  </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
                <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>application.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>    
<modules>
   <module>mock_server</module>
</modules>
</project>
```

Here is my mockserver pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.nulogix</groupId>
    <artifactId>billing_mediator</artifactId>
    <version>${nulogix-release-number}-${git.version.number}</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.nulogix</groupId>
  <artifactId>mock_server</artifactId>
  <version>${nulogix-release-number}-${git.version.number}</version>
  <name>mock_server</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>0.14.0</maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>
        <jaxb2-specVersion>2.2</jaxb2-specVersion>
        <git-commit-id-plugin.version>2.2.4</git-commit-id-plugin.version>
        <nulogix-release-number>0.9.6_M2</nulogix-release-number>
        <git.version.number>${git.commit.time}.${git.commit.id.describe-short}</git.version.number>
        <nulogix-billing-response-schema>nulogixBillingResponse_1.1.xsd</nulogix-billing-response-schema>
         </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformats-text</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0.pr1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-jaxb2-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>id1-generate-service-end-point-from-wsdl</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <specVersion>${jaxb2-specVersion}</specVersion>
                            <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>*.wsdl</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/xjc/billing_endpoint</generateDirectory>
                            <generatePackage>com.nulogix.billing.service</generatePackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>id2-generate-pojo-from-request-xsd</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <specVersion>${jaxb2-specVersion}</specVersion>
                            <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/request</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>StudyDetailsSchema_3.17.6.12.xsd</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/request</bindingDirectory>
                            <bindingIncludes>
                                <include>StudyDetailsSchema_3.17.6.12.xjb</include>
                            </bindingIncludes>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/xjc/request_model</generateDirectory>
                            <generatePackage>com.nulogix.billing.model.request</generatePackage>                            
                        </configuration>                
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>id3-generate-pojo-from-response-xsd</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <specVersion>${jaxb2-specVersion}</specVersion>
                            <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/response</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>${nulogix-billing-response-schema}</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/xjc/response_model</generateDirectory>                           
                            <generatePackage>com.nulogix.billing.model.response</generatePackage>                   
                        </configuration>                
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
                  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> <!-- surefire plugin version managed by Spring Boot -->
   <configuration>
      <skipTests>true</skipTests>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>unit-tests</id>
      <phase>test</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>test</goal>
       </goals>
       <configuration>
         <skipTests>false</skipTests>
         <includes>
           <include>**/*Test.java</include>
         </includes>
       </configuration>
     </execution>
     <execution>
       <id>integration-tests</id>
       <phase>integration-test</phase>
       <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
       </goals>
       <configuration>
         <skipTests>false</skipTests>
         <includes>
           <include>**/*IT.*</include>
        </includes>
       </configuration>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <dateFormat>yyyyMMdd-HHmmss</dateFormat><!--  human-readable part of the version id -->
                    <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile><!-- somehow necessary. otherwise the variables are not available in the pom -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                  <configuration>
                    <archive>
                      <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Version>${nulogix-release-number}-${git.version.number}</Implementation-Version>
                        <Git-Version-Number>${git.version.number}</Git-Version-Number>
                      </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                  </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My Mock Server App will run but my main app will not (mediator)

Comment: Your problem, ultimately, is that 'version' should not contain an expression.

Comment: More specifically, `git.version.number` is dynamically set by a plugin but is required before the plugin has been invoked.

Comment: @Michael what should I put instead? I have tried putting in 0.9.6_M2 as the version number but it says it can't find that artifact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use properties in the version number of your project, you need you the ci-friendly properties (https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html). Other properties can only be used in dependencies, not in your own version number.

Comment: Whenever I try to set a version number it says it can't find the local artifact jar. Is it because main is declared as POM and it can't find the jar?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question. Have you corrected `<version>${nulogix-release-number}-${git.version.number}</version>` yet?

Comment: I am still confused on how to fix it, I am not sure on what to put instead.

Comment: There are only three properties can be part of a version number. These are `${revision}`, `${sha1}` and `${changelist}`.

Comment: it still says that it cannot find the artifact.jar for ${revision}

Comment: Where did you set `${revision}` ?

Comment: at both my poms(child and parent) as shown in Multimodule dependency in your link

Comment: I mean: At which place do you give `${revision}` a value?

Comment: In the properties

Comment: You probably cannot do it through other properties, at least not in the POM.